# jenkins error after build successful

Tags: jenkins, symfony-2.3, jdepend

I have a problem with jenkins. It reports that the build of my symfony2 project ist successful, but directly after that it crashes with

```
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsPublisher aborted due to exception
java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
```

I have no clue why and I don't find any helpfull on the net for this error. 
It apperead out of the blue. yesterday the build was done correctly.

here is my log:

```
 jslint:
 [exec] Result: 1

 build:

 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 Total time: 13 minutes 21 seconds
 [CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
 [CHECKSTYLE] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/checkstyle.xml
 [CHECKSTYLE] Parsing 1 files in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DEVELOPMENT/workspace
 [CHECKSTYLE] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DEVELOPMENT/workspace/build/logs/checkstyle.xml of module  with 3 warnings.
 [CHECKSTYLE] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #54
 [DRY] Collecting duplicate code analysis files...
 [DRY] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml
 [DRY] Parsing 1 files in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DEVELOPMENT/workspace
 [DRY] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DEVELOPMENT/workspace/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml of module  with 207 warnings.
 [DRY] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #54
 [xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
 [xUnit] [INFO] - Processing PHPUnit-3.x (default)
 [xUnit] [INFO] - [PHPUnit-3.x (default)] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DEVELOPMENT/workspace' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit-3.x (default)'.
 [xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Failed Tests' threshold.
 [xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Skipped Tests' threshold.
 [xUnit] [INFO] - Setting the build status to SUCCESS
 [xUnit] [INFO] - Stopping recording.
 [JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
 [JDepend] Found 894 classes in 253 packages
 ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsPublisher aborted due to exception
 java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
at hudson.plugins.violations.parse.AbstractParser.expectNextTag(AbstractParser.java:262)
at hudson.plugins.violations.types.pmd.PMDParser.execute(PMDParser.java:39)
at hudson.plugins.violations.parse.AbstractTypeParser.parse(AbstractTypeParser.java:57)
at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsCollector.doType(ViolationsCollector.java:187)
at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsCollector.invoke(ViolationsCollector.java:114)
at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsCollector.invoke(ViolationsCollector.java:25)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:906)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:879)
at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsPublisher.perform(ViolationsPublisher.java:74)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:776)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:726)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1618)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the problem comes at a post-build action! Maybe, you don't have any data in the input file for JDepend, as I see from the error log. You must see if you give the correct path to the file and also, you must be sure that the file have some content... maybe the path is correct but the file is empty...